# Why background color are included in png image of ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I am an absolute beginner to Android. I am learning how to design a layout. But I am having problem with ImageView:

When I set the `src` of ImageView with a PNG file, the dark color background is automatically added to all the images like in screenshot:

[image]

The real image of is like this: (There's no background)

[image]

This is the xml layout for my toolbar and I did not set any background for the ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_open_sidebar"
            android:src="@drawable/open_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_calendar"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So how can I make that PNG image transparent or with the same background as the toolbar? I mean, how to remove that default dark background color?

Comment: try adding `android:backgroud="@android:color/transparent"` to your ImageButton s

Comment: Thanks . It worked. Please just post your answer. I will green up it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because you are using `ImageButton` android adds a default background to it.
you can add `android:backgroud="@android:color/transparent"` to your `ImageButton`s and force android to use transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

It is Default property of ImageButton. This won't happen in ImageView so update your question. Use ImageView or set background of ImageButton to null or a transparent color to fix it

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, then instead of copy and paste of .png file, right click on drawable and select New -> ImageAsset and then select the image which you want to have in drawable folder. It will remove the dark background part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Open image in explorer, right click and go to "properties", go to details tab and check the Bit depth. From my experience android studio adds black background if it is not "32". I don't know why it does that but it does not apply transparency otherwise. 
I just edit image with "paint.net" and resave it as 32bit.
Its a workaround but works for me everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change you parent layout background color.

This

**android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"**

to

**aandroid:background="any colour code"**

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the imageview to `"#00000000"`
It should do the trick.
The first two hexa-digits in the 8 hexa-digits in a color mark opacity
00 is fully transparent and FF is fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

In your relative layout you have this background:
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
check this color in colors.xlm